# Xcode - Setting Zombie enabled in two different places?

Tags: xcode, nszombieenabled

I've set to enable Zombies (`NSZombieEnabled`) in the Arguments tab in the scheme. But I just recently noticed that there is a tab called Diagnostics where you can tick a box called "Enable Zombie Objects".

Are these two equivalent ways of enabling zombies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seems they are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-on-xcode-4):

> Environment variables are now part of the "scheme".
>
> If you edit the scheme you want to turn on zombies for, go to the "Run
>   Foo.app" stage in the left panel, and the "Arguments" tab on the
>   right. You can then add NSZombieEnabled to the "Environment Variables"
>   section and set the value to YES, as you could in Xcode 3.
>
> In Xcode 4.1 and above, there's also checkbox on the "Diagnostics" tab
>   of the "Run" stage to "Enable Zombie Objects".